# Count results that have different column value related to same ID

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm new to SQL and looking for help on how to best do this.

I have 2 tables with the following columns:
**Investors**: Round ID, Investor Name, Investor City, Investor Country
**Rounds**: Round ID, Company Name, Company City, Company Country

I joined them to get this result

| Round ID | Investor Country | Company Country |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | US | Spain |
| 1 | UK | Spain |
| 1 | Spain | Spain |
| 2 | France | Germany |
| 2 | UK | Germany |
| 3 | UK | Italy |
| 3 | Italy | Italy |

I will need to get the number of investors (per round ID) which have their country different from the Company Country, So like for Round 1 I will have 2, for Round 2 it's 0 and for round 3 it's 1.

How could I do this?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you considered using a `COUNT` and a `CASE` expression? What have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

Just use conditional aggregation:

```
select round,
       sum(case when investor_country <> company_company then 1 else 0 end) as cnt
from t
group by round;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your expected output, I think you need the `count = 0` in case there do not exists a single record for `investor country = company country` and if there is, then you need all other record count.

You can use conditions as follows:

```
select round_id,
       case when count(case when investor_country = company_company then 1 end) = 0 
            then 0
            else count(case when investor_country <> company_company then 1 end)
       end as cnt
from your_table t
group by round_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need diffrent counts:

```
SELECT 
  RoundId,
  SUM(IIF(InvestorCountry != CompanyCountry,1,0)) AS Count
FROM
  YOUR_TABLE_OR_VIEW
GROUP BY 
  RoundId
```

If you need difrent count and when all result of a same Round are difrent you want zero:

```
SELECT
  t.RoundId, 
  IIF(t.Count = t.DiffrentCount,0,t.DiffrentCount) 'Count'
FROM 
(
SELECT 
    RoundId,
    SUM(1)                                          AS 'Count',
    SUM(IIF(InvestorCountry != CompanyCountry,1,0)) AS 'DiffrentCount',
FROM
    YOUR_TABLE_OR_VIEW
GROUP BY 
    RoundId
)t
```